# Custom pagination with stored procedure in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, stored-procedures, pagination

I need to fetch near about 40000 row from database and bind into gridview and after that this data need to export to excel and PDF.
when I'm binding the rows with simple strored procedure then it takes long time near about 5-6 mints.
So I have written a stored procedure for custom pagination.

My strored procedure is following..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetTarnsactionPaging]
  @PageIndex INT = 1
  ,@PageSize INT = 10
  ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
 BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
  select   APP.AppName AS "Application Name",
  TRA.OS_Name as "OS",TRA.MSISDN,TRA.RequestDateTime AS "Request DateTime Stamp",
  TRA.ResponseDateTime AS "Reponse DateTime Stamp" ,TRA.IP,TRA.UserDetails,TRA.UserAgent,TRA.OperationType ,
  TRA.OperationDetails AS "Opperation Details",TRA.Status 
 INTO #Results
FROM TTSL_Application_Master APP INNER JOIN TTSL_ApplicationTransactionDetails_Master TRA     
ON APP.AppID=TRA.ApplicationID   
 WHERE  TRA.ApplicationID=2 AND TRA.RequestDateTime >= 2014-11-02 AND TRA.ResponseDateTime <= 2014-11-03
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (
order by App_TransactionDetailsID
  )AS RowNumber


  SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM #Results

  SELECT * FROM #Results
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

  DROP TABLE #Results
```

END

When I'm executing the stored procedure then following error is showing..

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure uspGetTarnsactionPaging, Line 18
>   Invalid column name 'App_TransactionDetailsID'.

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetTarnsactionPaging]
  @PageIndex INT = 1
  ,@PageSize INT = 10
  ,@RecordCount INT OUTPUT
AS
 BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON;
  select ROW_NUMBER() OVER
  (
   order by App_TransactionDetailsID
  )AS RowNumber, APP.AppName AS "Application Name",
  TRA.OS_Name as "OS",TRA.MSISDN,TRA.RequestDateTime AS "Request DateTime Stamp",
  TRA.ResponseDateTime AS "Reponse DateTime Stamp" ,TRA.IP,TRA.UserDetails,TRA.UserAgent,TRA.OperationType ,
  TRA.OperationDetails AS "Opperation Details",TRA.Status 
 INTO #Results
FROM TTSL_Application_Master APP INNER JOIN TTSL_ApplicationTransactionDetails_Master TRA     
ON APP.AppID=TRA.ApplicationID   
 WHERE  TRA.ApplicationID=2 AND TRA.RequestDateTime >= 2014-11-02 AND TRA.ResponseDateTime <= 2014-11-03
Order by App_TransactionDetailsID Desc  


  SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(*)
  FROM #Results

  SELECT * FROM #Results
  WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN(@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1 AND(((@PageIndex -1) * @PageSize + 1) + @PageSize) - 1

  DROP TABLE #Results
```

Comment: Query Executed successfully but the data is not showing..  :(